# Ubuntu 14.04 unknown (external) monitor every time after reboot

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, display

I connected an external monitor (LG 21 in) with my laptop (Lenovo ThinkPad 15 in). It used to be working ok, but now every time after reboot, the LG monitor has very low resolution, I have manually set the resolutions like these:

`xrandr --newmode "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync`

`xrandr --addmode VGA1 1680x1050_60.00`

Then it seems to work, but again the problem will happen again after a reboot. Is there a way to fix this issue permanently? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem with one of my monitors as well.  The best suggestion I can give you would be to put those commands into a script file.  I named mine `fixres.bsh` and put it in my home `~` directory.  Using your code below, I added the interpreter line as the first line, then added your code.

```
#!/bin/bash
xrandr --newmode "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1680x1050_60.00
```

After you create the file, make it executable:

```
sudo chmod +x fixres.bsh
```

then add it to your start up.

Press the SuperKey (Windows Key) on your keyboard to bring up the dash, then type in `startup applications` to find the *Startup Applications* app.

[image]

Then once in the app, click the Add button

[image]

The add the following line to the command:

[image]

```
bash -c "sleep 5 && /home/username/fixres.bsh"
```

I like to give it a sleep of 5 seconds at startup to allow other applications to complete loading.

Click *Save* when completed and close the *Startup Applications* app.

Hope this helps!

Comment: To have the same problem is great :)